# Android wifi getting frequency of the connected Wifi

Tags: android, android-wifi

Well i have ScanResults and from there i can have SSID , BSSID , Frequency of all the wifi's.

```
List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
```

Also i have the Connected wifi info so from there also i am having SSID of connected and BSSID of the connected wifi.

```
WifiManager wifi;
WifiInfo info;
wifi = (WifiManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
```

Now i only want to have the frequency of the connected wifi but when i check SSID and BSSID they can be same for 2 network. Now how can i find the frequency of the connected Wifi.

Also from that wifi i want to have corresponding channel no.

i found a table for that

CHANNEL NUMBER  LOWER Freq(GHZ) CENTER Freq(GHZ)  UPPER Freq(GHZ)

1                2401                 2412                 2423

2                2404                 2417                 2428

3                2411                 2422                 2433

4                2416                 2427                 2438

5                2421                 2432                 2443

6                2426                 2437                 2448

7                2431                 2442                 2453

8                2436                 2447                 2458

9                2441                 2452                 2463

10               2451                 2457                 2468

11               2451                 2462                 2473

12               2456                 2467                 2478

13               2461                 2472                 2483

14               2473                 2484                 2495

Want to know whether sdk always provides center freq of this table and also what abt other freq like 5Ghz etc?

Comment: hi @amit hooda did you get your answer.. actually i am also concerned about the other frequency bands.

Comment: you need the channel no from frequency??

Comment: yes i am also loking for it

Comment: you can http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels find here list of channels also for 5GHz you have another table and use these for frequency to channel conversion. I found all these correct and xactly same frequencies were returned by android SDK.

Comment: I don't think there is any Android API to get the frequency info of Wi-Fi connection

Answer (score 1):

The frequency from WifiInfo is only available since Lollipop (API 21) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getFrequency()

```
android.net.wifi.WifiInfo

public int getFrequency ()

Returns the current frequency in FREQUENCY_UNITS.
```

Answer (score 1):

**You Can Try.**

```
 WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getContext().getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
     int frequency = wifiInfo.getFrequency();
```

**Add Following Permission.**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```