# How check if current network connected is WIFI 5G?

Tags: android, wifi, 5g

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25912464/17564313) approach to check type of current connected network and works fine, except when is connected to WIFI 5G. How know if WIFI network connected is 5G? i only found [how check if device supports WIFI 5G](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607371/how-to-detect-whether-device-has-5ghz-wi-fi-or-not). Thanks in advance.

Comment: 5G belongs to a mobile connection. Not to wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is determine based in [WIFI frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48314319/17564313), eg:

```
private static boolean is24GHzWifi(int frequency) {
        return frequency > 2400 && frequency < 2500;
    }

    private static boolean is5GHzWifi(int frequency) {
        return frequency > 4900 && frequency < 5900;
    }
    
// ...

if (info.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {

            WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getContext().getSystemService(context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
            int frequency = wifiInfo.getFrequency();

            if (is24GHzWifi(frequency))
                return "WIFI 2.4G";
            else if (is5GHzWifi(frequency))
                return "WIFI 5G";
            else
                return "WIFI";
  }
```

Reference: [Android judge whether wifi is 2.4G or 5G](https://www.codetd.com/en/article/13992904)